# Jasper: collapse white space when string element is empty

Tags: jasper-reports

I need to collapse a field when it's null or empty.
I have this jrxml source code

```
<textField>
            <reportElement x="180" y="0" width="200" height="20" uuid="5d7e1430-4275-4c04-a609-b12adf976cd2"/>
            <textElement markup="styled">
                <font isBold="true"/>
            </textElement>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{title}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="false">
            <reportElement positionType="Float" x="180" y="20" width="200" height="20" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" uuid="3e10e11d-131e-4059-b885-0210e651b5bd">
                <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$F{vote} != null && !$F{vote}.equals("")]]></printWhenExpression>
            </reportElement>
            <textElement>
                <paragraph lineSpacing="Proportional"/>
            </textElement>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["Voto: "+$F{vote}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField>
            <reportElement x="180" y="40" width="200" height="30" uuid="2623f12e-a68f-4173-8f64-69a54ce50a0a"/>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{organisationName}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
```

The Field Vote sometimes is empty or null and with `$F{vote} != null && !$F{vote}.equals("")]` it isn't displayed, but the space remain white and it doesn't disappear.

**This is my result**

[image]

**This is what I want**

[image]

Where am I wrong?